# pytest how to take actions on setup failure

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I am trying to find a clean way to execute some code when the setup_class method of py.test fails.  Given the following example:

```
class TestClass:

    @classmethod
    def setup_class(self):
        print("I am performing setup actions!")

    def test_one(self):
        x = "this"
        assert 'h' in x

    def setup_cleanup(self):
        print("I want to perfrom some cleanup action!")
```

How do I get the setup_cleanup method to be triggered by py.test if setup raises an exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this kind of decorator catch exceptions in the setup_class method:

```
def is_failed_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        except AssertionError:
            # Your code here.
            raise
    return wrapper

@is_failed_decorator
@classmethod
def setup_class(self):
```